# alignment of div's one below the other is failing

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have multiple angularJS UI grids on my page. After the UI grids are displayed I need to show some more details, which are kept in the divs which need to be displayed below the grids.

[Click here for demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XwCpnGjcnyKqMnmc1kLC?p=preview)

Please find the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
/*imports here*/
     <style>
           .grid {
                height: 5%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
         <style>
            #info_div_name {
                width:auto;
                height:auto;
                float:left;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            #info_div_time {
                width:auto;
                height:auto;
                float:right;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            #info_div_note {
                width:inherit;
                height:auto;
                position:static;
                clear:both;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
      <body>

    <div>
         <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class='inline1' style="width:40%;height: 20%;padding-left: 11px;" id="info_div_name">
            <div ui-grid="{ data: data, columnDefs: columnDefs,enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        enableFiltering: true, }" class="executiveSummaryGrid" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellnav></div> <br>
          </div>
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class='inline1' style="width: 40%;height: 20%;padding-right: 11px;" id="info_div_time">
            <div ui-grid="{ data: data, columnDefs: columnDefs,enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        enableFiltering: true, }" class="myGrid" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellnav></div> <br>
         </div>

        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class='inline1' style="width: 40%;height: 20%;padding-left: 11px;" id="info_div_name">
            <div ui-grid="{ data: data, columnDefs: columnDefs,enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        enableFiltering: true, }" class="mileStonesGrid" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellnav></div> <br>
         </div>

    </div> 
    <div style = "background-color:Red;height:50px;width:100px;float:left"></div>
    <div style = "background-color:Blue;height:50px;width:100px;float:left"></div>
    <div style = "background-color:Green;height:50px;width:100px;margin-left:200px"></div>

      </body>
```

I was not able to display the divs which are displaying the colors red, blue, and green below the angularJS UI grid.

Please suggest how I can align the last three divs (displaying colors red, blue, and green) horizontally in a single row below the angularJS UI grids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit based on comment:**

- Add `float:left;` to the green div and remove/comment: `margin-left: 200px;`:
- Set `clear: left;` or `clear: both;` on red div.

Snippet below:

```
<div style = "background-color:Red;height:50px;width:100px;float:left;clear:both;"></div>
<div style = "background-color:Blue;height:50px;width:100px;float:left"></div>
<div style = "background-color:Green;height:50px;width:100px;float:left"></div>
```

**[---> External Fiddle here <---](http://plnkr.co/edit/vnuHobwLnCOhyXlfiHTZ?p=preview)**

[image]

Comment: I want to add that div with color's below the grid, not to the side.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `float:left;` to the green div and remove `margin-left: 200px;`
2. Add `clear: both;` to red div